# sql date query gets corrct record but not inserting properly

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
INSERT INTO job_seeker_membership (mem_seeker, mem_plan, mem_payoption,  
mem_date, mem_paystatus, mem_reqstatus, mem_status, mem_exdate)  
VALUES ('107', '11', 1, NOW(), 0, 1, 1, 2015-08-17)
```

above query running correctly but its inserting like `0000-00-00` in place of `2015-08-17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your field is set up as `Date` then it needs a string value in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Passing it `2015-08-12`, for example, is not in string format; it is in integer format. Use: `'2015-08-12'` instead

For your problem specifically:

```
INSERT INTO job_seeker_membership
(mem_seeker, mem_plan, mem_payoption, 
mem_date, mem_paystatus, mem_reqstatus, mem_status, mem_exdate) 
VALUES 
('107', '11', 1, NOW(), 0, 1, 1, '2015-08-17')
```